# How can you use python to tell LaTex to compile a .tex file?

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is a way to use Python to command my LaTeX compiler to load a text file, save it as a LaTeX file and then compile the LaTeX file into a pdf.  The text file, when I load it manually and save it as a .tex file, creates the PDF that I want.

Comment: This is more of a python question. You can do that in python with the latex package. Look it up on pypi.

Comment: what do you mean by save as tex file? just rename the file (that isn't needed) or adding tex markup, in which case which markup? eg will your txt file have `%` or `$` or other characters that need to be quoted?